# How to resolve error in AWS Route 53 - import zone file error : Multiple Distinct TTL values?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am trying to import a zone file from Linode in to Amazon Route 53and I get the following error

```
Error parsing zone file: One resource cannot have multiple distinct TTL values
```

I know what it is trying to say, but I cannot find any where in the file the TTL values which are duplicates. Any hint is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the zone file?

Comment: @user618886 welcome to Stack Overflow.  This community's preferred way of handling a situation where you solve your own problem independently is not to edit the question, but rather to post and mark as accepted, an actual answer to your own question -- if it is a question and answer that will be useful to future visitors (as, indeed, is the stated purpose of the site -- Q&A that are useful to others).  Please consider doing that, as it improves the quality of our content as well as your future reputation scores, since people who find it helpful will upvote your answer and/or question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went through the zone file by eliminating sections and trying to import it. Finally figured out the section that was giving me the grief. The MX records shown below are exactly as imported from Linode.

```
@       3600    MX  1   ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@       3600    MX  5   ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@           MX  5   ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@           MX  10  ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@           MX  10  ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
```

If I remove 3600 from the first two lines, I was able to import the file. Not sure why Linode gives out this file. So MX records now look like this when I import them.

```
@           MX  1   ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@           MX  5   ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@           MX  5   ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@           MX  10  ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@           MX  10  ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
```

Answer (score 18):

I was getting the same error importing a zone file from DNSimple into Route 53. My problem was that I had multiple TXT records for the same domain, and those TXT records had different TTL values. In Route 53, records of the same type (TXT, MX, CNAME, etc) for the same domain or subdomain get grouped together in a "record set" with one TTL value, so my zone file was breaking it. As soon as I changed them all to the same TTL, the zone file could be imported.

Answer (score 0):

I had follwed step by step guide from http://blog.domenech.org/2014/12/how-to-transfer-your-dns-configuration-to-aws-route-53.html.

The guideance did perfectly well. The point to be noted is that **I need to udpate TTL value for each entry with one number** so that, `Route53` can group some value to a single entry, for me it was **txt record** for **spf**.